# Get number of rows of a text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a string that can be anything and I have a text object in my scene which has a set width and a changeable height.

Is there a built-in function that counts how many rows my string would have in that text object so that I can adjust the height of it? I want to do this because I need a background **only** at the text and not anywhere else.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to do this because I need a background only at the text and not anywhere else.

It appears to me that this should be able to solve your problem:

> In order to make a Rect Transform with a Text component on it fit the text content, add a Content Size Fitter component to the same Game Object which has the Text component. Then set both the Horizontal Fit and Vertical Fit dropdowns to the Preferred setting.

In your case you want to control the Horizontal but not the vertical, so try set the Vertical setting to "Preferred".

If this does not work directly on your text component you may want to make the text component a child of the grey panel box and then add the contentfitter to it as well.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIFitContentSize.html

Disclaimer: I didn't test this Component based attempt, but I believe it may be the solution or lead you closer to one.

Answer (score 4):

While Doh09's answer is certainly accurrate, you can also query the [`UI.Text.preferredHeight`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-preferredHeight.html) property, asking the Text object how tall the text is and using that value to change the size of your background object yourself.

Of course, both answers assume you are using the New UI text and not TextMesh or OnGUI. If you are not using the New UI, then I suggest changing to using [the New UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui).

You can see an example usage of this in my own project [here](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/game/GuiManager.cs#L66) where I compute the text's desired width and height and modify the RectTransform until the object's preferred size is within a layout-preferred ratio. Here's one of the final sections (with some alterations to make it understandable):

```
Text t = <some Text object>
float height = t.preferredHeight;
float width = t.preferredWidth;
((RectTransform)tooltipGO.transform).SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, (width / 4) + 8);
((RectTransform)tooltipGO.transform).SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Vertical, (height / 4) + 7.5f);
```

The divide-by-four and offsets to account for relative scaling between the text and the background and some edge padding.

Comment: I am using TextMeshPro, do you think it is hard to switch?

Comment: @squeezyPig `Vector4 bounds = m_textMeshPro.bounds;` will give you the bounds. Do note that if you want this immediately after changing the content you need to call `m_textMeshPro.ForceMeshUpdate();` first. ([Source](https://forum.unity.com/threads/textmeshprougui-get-the-width-prefersize-of-the-rendered-text.476311/))